# Is there a specific word for a cross-language mondegreen?

Tags: terminology

A mondegreen is a mishearing of a phrase (usually in a poem or song lyrics) as something else; the word itself is one of the best-known mondegreens: it comes from a mishearing of “And laid him on the green” as “And Lady Mondegreen”. Perhaps the best-known example is mishearing “’Scuse me while I kiss the sky” in the Jimi Hendrix Experience song *Purple Haze* as “’Scuse me while I kiss this guy”.

A cross-language mondegreen, then, would be a word/phrase uttered or sung in one language, which is being misheard as an unrelated word/phrase in another language.

Is there an English term for such a thing? And are there any quintessential, defining examples of it along the lines of the ‘kiss this guy’ one for English-only mondegreens?

Comment: Can you provide an example for what you mean?

Comment: Not sounding sore, but I presume the question was clear. More so, I was actually asking for examples of cross-language mondegreens.

Comment: @Monzoor Unfortunately, questions which seek examples are a poor fit for the Q&A structure of SE, and as such are broadly considered off topic. The question of whether there's a word for such mondegreens is legit, if you'd like to restrict your attention to just that topic (though I suspect the answer is "no"; but I've been wrong before and I will be wrong again).

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question, as it's much clearer now what you're looking for. You're going to have to wait for 4 more people to cast their votes with mine. You can speed that up by asking people to do so on [meta], or you can just wait.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it even clearer and also make it less of an open-ended list request, and I've also added my reopen vote to the list.

Comment: You might be interested in a deliberate bilingual mishearing [Mots d'Heure: Gousses, Rames](http://www.blueridgejournal.com/poems/mots10-lit-elle.htm)

Comment: Surely the word for the phenomenon of mishearing is *mondegreen*. Why should a mishearing of a foreign phrase be any different? Indeed, why should a foreign phrase be misinterpreted as a phrase in your own language at all? A single example would help demonstrate that that misinterpretation does actually occur (and could therefore be named); but if it does and has a name I reckon that name is *mondegreen.* I don't believe English would borrow a word where it already has one.

Comment: Would "Chaise _lounge_" count? The corresponding original French is  "chaise _longue_" or 'long chair'.

Comment: Why would there be?? This is just silly. Sorry.

Comment: My father told me his sister used to call him a messy boco at the dinner table, and he didn't know why. His sister was taking French. "pass me the milk, messy boco."

Comment: @Mitch, also "cows and ducks" - O Sybilli, si ergo
Fortibus es in ero
O nobili, demis trux
Sevatis enim causen dux.   I've seen it rendered as German as well as Latin.

Comment: @PhilSweet Gesundheit!

Comment: @Joachim A word for a "cross-language" mondegreen.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is a very commonly used term, but [soramimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soramimi) seems to fit:

> interpreting lyrics in one language as similar-sounding lyrics in another language.

It is a Japanese term which is borrowed into English.

It has been, or still is, quite a hype in the Netherlands, where the phenomenon is known as ['Mama Appelsap'](https://superrradio.bnn.nl/mama-appelsap) (lit. *mom apple juice*), a misheard lyrics from the bridge of Michael Jackson's *Wanna Be Starting Something*:

> Ma me se, ma me sa, ma ma coo sa

Comment: Fabulous examples on the Superradio site. I am betting that this is a phenomenon that is less commonly recognized in English-speaking countries, because we don't tend to listen to a lot of music in other languages.

Comment: In fact, the only popular non-English songs I can think of in recent memory are [Psy's Gangnam Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0) and [O-Zone's Dragostea Din Tei](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRx5PrAlUdY), for which there were many "Mama Appelsapjes" noted by young listeners. At the time, I used the term "mondegreen" to explain it to my Top-40-fan daughter, because I had never heard another term.

Comment: Amusingly enough, the example wording that you quote from Michael Jackson, was actually taken, syllable for syllable, from "[Soul Makossa](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sca_esv=573626709&tbm=vid&q=Soul+Makossa&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR0-bCxPiBAxXnnWoFHfbXCM4Q8ccDegQIYBAD&biw=1440&bih=705&dpr=2#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:a4367c9b,vid:EF92yOsv3Y8,st:0)" by Manu Dibango. Dibango was from Cameroon, and "makossa" supposedly means "I will dance" in Douala (a West African language).

Comment: Note that *soramimi* is **deliberate** mishearing.